# How to change title of some text input depending on a radio with jquery?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, title, textinput

As you can see on http://jsbin.com/erivi/ I'm using Jquery to change some image (and image attribute) depending on radio button selected, I'm also removing form text when clicking inside it.

And now what I'm trying to do is to change the text of the form depending on the radio button checked.

For example when clicking on "Choice 3" we should see "Text of input 3".

You can see & edit my code live here: http://jsbin.com/erivi/edit

The part I need to improve is:

```
  imgFldr = 'http://download.kde.org/khotnewstuff/icons/previews/'; 
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() { 
   var strarr = this.title.split('|'); 
   if(strarr.length < 2) return; 
   $('#'+this.name).attr('src', imgFldr+strarr[0]).attr('alt', strarr[1]).attr('title', starr[2]); 
});
```

And particularly `.attr('title', starr[2]);` which is supposed to change title depending on the 3rd part of my radio title (exemple: `title='m602-1.png|Logo 3|Text of input 3'` )

Thanks :)

Edit: I forgot to mention that I'm using several forms on my real code, that's why I'm looking for a way to do this without the particular name of the text input in order to avoid repeating script for other text input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** The id of the input textbox has to be unique. Additionally, you need to set `.attr('title',strarr[2])`, `.val(strarr[2])` and the hint class inside the radio button's click event. Also some changes need to be made to your `inputdynvalue` plugin.

Please see the complete updated working code at http://jsbin.com/akawo

**Updated Plug-in code**

```
(function($) { 
    $.fn.inputdynvalue = function (options) { 
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.inputdynvalue.defaults, options); 
        return this.each(function(){ 
            var hvalue = opts.htext; 
            switch (opts.htext) { 
                case 'title' : hvalue = $(this).attr('title'); break; 
                case 'value' : hvalue = $(this).attr('value'); break; 
            } 
            $(this).attr('value', hvalue).addClass(opts.hclass) 
            .unbind('focus blur') 
            .bind('focus', function() {                       
                if (this.value === this.title) { 
                    this.value = ''; 
                    $(this).removeClass(opts.hclass); 
                } 
            }) 
            .bind('blur', function() { 
                if (this.value === '') { 
                    this.value = this.title; 
                    $(this).addClass(opts.hclass); 
                } 
            }); 
        }); 
    }; 
    $.fn.inputdynvalue.defaults = { 
        htext: 'title', 
        hclass: 'hint' 
    }; 
})(jQuery); 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input[type='text']").inputdynvalue(); 
});
```

**Updated Radio Button Click Event Handler**

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function() { 
   var strarr = this.title.split('|'); 
   if(strarr.length < 2) return; 
   $('#'+this.name).attr('src', imgFldr+strarr[0]).attr('alt', strarr[1]); 
   $('#'+this.name+'_text')
      .attr('title',strarr[2])
      .val(strarr[2])
      .addClass('hint'); 
});
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer but there is still the same problem with your code it does change the text when clicking on radio button but when you click inside the form it only removes text when the first radio button is selected.
When "Choice 2" is selected if you click inside the form the text isn't removed. This has something to do with my inputdynvalue script on top of source code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <img id="iymok" src="http://download.kde.org/khotnewstuff/icons/previews/m732-1.png" alt="Alt by default" />
        <input type="text" id="iymok_text" title="Blablabla Text 1" />
        <label><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="iymok" title="m133-1.png|Logo 1|Blablabla Text 1" />Choice 1</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="iymok" title='m203-1.png|Logo 2|Text of input 2' />Choice 2</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="iymok" title='m602-1.png|Logo 3|Text of input 3' />Choice 3</label>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    imgFldr = 'http://download.kde.org/khotnewstuff/icons/previews/';
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
        var strarr = this.title.split('|');
        if (strarr.length >= 3) {
               $('#'+this.name).attr('src', imgFldr+strarr[0]).attr('alt', strarr[1]).attr('title', strarr[2]);
               $('#'+this.name+'_text').attr('title', strarr[2]);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work plus I forgot to mention that I'm using several forms on my real code, so is there any other way to do this without telling the name of the text input?

Comment: Ah, fixed! Remember, the 'id' attribute must be unique. You shouldn't have multiple elements on a page with the same id.

Comment: Almost perfect, just need some way to remove the text when clicking on it, and turn it back when clicking outside of the form (and put text back depending on radio button selected) as it works for Choice 1 but not for 2 other.

Comment: It doesn't change the title anymore even if the text is removed when clicking on it as before… Does it work for you ?

Comment: You were very helpful Tyson but José Basilio provided some better answer. Thanks anyway.